# Why image doesn't show up within a DIV in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- default stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css">

<!-- if ie version 9 or less -->

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css">
<![endif]-->

<div id="subpageHeaderImageSection">
    <div id="subpageHeaderLeft">
        <img id="igm" src="theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

***defaultStyle.css***:

```
#subpageHeaderImageSection {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#subpageHeaderLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#igm {
    display: none;
}
```

**defaultStyle_ie.css**:

```
#subpageHeaderImageSection {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#subpageHeaderLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
}
#igm {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I had to add an image for the IE because the `background-size:` property is not yet supported.

If I remove the `display: none` from the `defaultStyle.css`, the IE8 shows it correctly but the other browsers stretches the images fully. If I keep it, the other browsers displays it correctly but IE8 doesn't display the image at all.

How do I fix the above so it works for all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control size in ie < 9 you must use the filter property in css

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

and still use background-size. It will read the background-size of 100% in this case and use it

Comment: Keep the `background: url() no-repeat` as well?

Comment: I did this: `background: url('../theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png') no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png', sizingMethod='scale');` and the same thing is happening as before :/

Comment: I had to use a conditional statement for the image itself and everything is working fine now.

Comment: glad you got it to work. If you remove the code I gave you, will it fail? Was a combination of my code and yours? Sometimes you have to inspect with the browser to see if a JS is affecting the CSS behavior

Comment: I didn't have to use the filter at all. But thank you for the answer. UPVOTED & ACCEPTED.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't soliciting. I was merely trying to figure out if I did help you. But thank you anyway. Let us know if you run into anything else :)

Comment: I know :) I just wanted to let you know my solution so in case the future you are aware of it. Thanks for the help and I sure will.